# Table Alignment (Making the content in multicolumn middle and bold)

Tags: tables, tabularx

Firstly, how to my multicolumn content into middle that looks better?
[image]

Secondly, I am facing the problem of making the bold of the first row. I using the table format previously. Once I added `\textbf{}`, the content is outlined.

```
\textbf{Example} & \textbf{Fruit Example Example} & \textbf{Mean} &  {\thead{Std. Deviation}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
```

[image: taby]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, array}
\usepackage{tabulary,siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx} %for table multirow
%for table multirow

\begin{document} 

\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}          
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}  % Centred fix width column

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XcS[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=1.5]}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Example} & \textbf{Fruit Example Example} & \textbf{Mean} &  {\thead{Std. Deviation}}& {\thead{Std. Error}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\thead{Fruit Fruit Example Example}} & AA & 42.00\% & 31.0000 & 5.80230 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & BB & 42.00\% & 17.8743 & 5.20 \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Total & 73.2 & 44.1257 & 5.22 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

 \usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
 \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx} 
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}  % Centred fix width column

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y c
                            S[table-format=2.2,
                              table-space-text-post=\%]
                            S[table-format=2.4]
                            S[table-format=1.5]}
\toprule
\thead[bl]{Example} 
    & \thead[b]{Fruit\\ Example\\ Example} 
        & {\thead[b]{Mean}} 
            &  {\thead[b]{Std.\\ Deviation}}
                & {\thead[b]{Std.\\ Error}}  \\
\midrule
\multirow{3.6}{=}{Fruit Fruit Example Example}
    & AA & 42.00\% & 31.0000 & 5.80230  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & BB & 42.00\% & 17.8743 & 5.20     \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Total & 73.2 & 44.1257 & 5.22     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- it is sufficient if you load each package only once
- some packages load other packages, for example `tabularx` loads `array`, so you not need to load it again
- if you defined some new type of columns, please use them in table code
- I have a strong feeling, that you already asked a similar question before ...

**Addendum**
Inspired by @Bernard comment below I suggest you to consider the following changes to your table design:

- insert small distance between numbers end percent sign
- round numbers with similar meaning to have equal number of decimal digits. This can be simply done with using of the `siunitx` options `round-mode = places` and `round-precision=...` (see MWE below)
       }

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}  % Centred fix width column

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\sisetup{round-mode = places,
         round-precision=3,
         }

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y c
                            S[table-format=2.2,
                              round-precision=2,
                              table-space-text-post=\%]
                       *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                            }
\toprule
\thead[bl]{Example}
    & \thead[b]{Fruit\\ Example\\ Example}
        & {\thead[b]{Mean}}
            &  {\thead[b]{Std.\\ Deviation}}
                & {\thead[b]{Std.\\ Error}}  \\
\midrule
\multirow{3.6}{=}{Fruit Fruit Example Example}
    & AA    & 42.00\,\% & 31.0000 & 5.80230  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & BB    & 42.00\,\% & 17.8743 & 5.2      \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
    & Total & 73.2\,\%  & 44.1257 & 5.22     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: @Bernard, you are right. I had prepared such a version which mimic `\SI{12.34}{\%}`, i e ˙1,.23\,\%`, but but -- now i don't know why -- didn't publish it. I will write an addendum asap.

Comment: if I want to add one more column on the far end right hand side, i editted `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y c
                            S[table-format=2.2,
                              round-precision=2,
                              table-space-text-post=\%]
                       *{3}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                            }`, and `\multirow{3.6}{=}{Fruit Fruit Example Example}
    & AA    & 42.00\,\% & 31.0000 & 5.80230 & 10` 
Why the last column is not centre, the `N` is towards left while the `10` is centre.

Comment: @ann, are all numbers in last column have tow integer and three decimal digits? If not, you need to define  ? in this case you need to define `table-format` for this column accordingly.

Comment: @Zakro, thanks. I got it. I used `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y c
                            S[table-format=2.2,
                              round-precision=2,
                              table-space-text-post=\%]
                       *{2}{S[table-format=2.3], [table-format=1.0]}`

Comment: @aan, number "10" has two digits ...  and you also forgot on `S` specifier :-(. So table preamble should be  `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Y c
                            S[table-format=2.2,
                              round-precision=2,
                              table-space-text-post=\%]
                       *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                            S[table-format=2.0]
                            }`